# Generate string permutations recursively; each character appears n times

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will generate all strings of length nm, with exactly n of each number 1, 2, ... m,

For instance all strings of length 6, with exactly two 1's, two 2's and two 3's e.g. 112233, 121233,

I managed to do this with just 1's and 2's using a recursive method, but can't seem to get something that works when I introduce 3's.

When m = 2, the algorithm I have is:

```
generateAllStrings(int len, int K, String str) 
{
    if(len == 0) 
    {
        output(str);
    }

   if(K > 0) 
   {
       generateAllStrings(len - 1, K - 1, str + '2'); 
    }      
   if(len > K)  
   {
        generateAllStrings(len - 1, K, str + '1'); 
    }
}
```

I've tried inserting similar conditions for the third number but the algorithm doesn't give a correct output. After that I wouldn't even know how to generalise for 4 numbers and above.

Is recursion the right thing to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a simple recursive algorithm, give each recursion the permutation so far (variable `perm`), and the number of occurances of each digit that is still available (array `count`).
Run the code snippet to generate all unique permutations for `n=2` and `m=4` (set: `11223344`).

```js
function permutations(n, m) {
    var perm = "", count = [];                   // start with empty permutation
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) count[i] = n;    // set available number for each digit = n
    permute(perm, count);                        // start recursion with "" and [n,n,n...]

    function permute(perm, count) {
        var done = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) { // iterate over all digits
            if (count[i] > 0) {                  // more instances of digit i available
                var c = count.slice();           // create hard copy of count array
                --c[i];                          // decrement count of digit i
                permute(perm + (i + 1), c);      // add digit to permutation and recurse
                done = false;                    // digits left over: not the last step
            }
        }
        if (done) document.write(perm + "<BR>"); // no digits left: complete permutation
    }
}

permutations(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to list off all distinct permutations of the string `111...1222...2...nnn....n`. There are nice algorithms for enumerating all distinct permutations of a string in time proportional to the length of the string, and they'd probably be a good way to go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using DFS (or BFS alternatively). We can define an graph such that each node contains one string and a node is connected to any node that holds a string with a pair of `int` swaped in comparison to the original string. This graph is connected, thus we can easily generate a set of all nodes; which will contain all strings that are searched:

```
set generated_strings
list nodes

nodes.add(generateInitialString(N , M))
generated_strings.add(generateInitialString(N , M))

while(!nodes.empty())
    string tmp = nodes.remove(0)

    for (int i in [0 , N * M))
        for (int j in distinct([0 , N * M) , i))
            string new = swap(tmp , i , j)
            if (!generated_strings.contains(new))
                nodes.add(new)
                generated_strings.add(new)

//generated_strings now contains all strings that can possibly be generated.
```